# Unexpected output with RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I'm trying to learn about RandomAccessFile but after creating a test program I'm getting some bizarre output.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class RandomAccessFileTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        // Create a new blank file
        File file = new File("RandomAccessFileTest.txt");
        file.createNewFile();
        
        // Open the file in read/write mode
        RandomAccessFile randomfile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        
        // Write stuff
        randomfile.write("Hello World".getBytes());
        
        // Go to a location
        randomfile.seek(0);
        
        // Get the pointer to that location
        long pointer = randomfile.getFilePointer();
        System.out.println("location: " + pointer);
        
        // Read a char (two bytes?)
        char letter = randomfile.readChar();
        System.out.println("character: " + letter);
        
        randomfile.close();
    }
}
```

This program prints out

> location: 0
>
> character: ?

Turns out that the value of letter was '䡥' when it should be 'H'.

I've found a question similar to this, and apparently this is caused by reading one byte instead of two, but it didn't explain how exactly to fix it.

Comment: Why not use [`writeChars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeChars-java.lang.String-)? Always read and write with the same encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written "Hello World" in the platform default encoding - which is likely to use a single byte per character.

You're then reading [`RandomAccessFile.readChar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readChar--) which always reads two bytes. Documentation:

> Reads a character from this file. This method reads two bytes from the file, starting at the current file pointer. If the bytes read, in order, are b1 and b2, where 0 <= b1, b2 <= 255, then the result is equal to:
>
> ```
>    (char)((b1 << 8) | b2)
> ```
>
> This method blocks until the two bytes are read, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.

So `H` and `e` are being combined into a single character - `H` is U+0048, `e` is U+0065, so assuming they've been written as ASCII character, you're reading bytes 0x48 and 0x65 and combining them into [U+4865](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4865/index.htm) which is a Han character for "a moving cart".

Basically, you shouldn't be using `readChar` to try to read this data.

Usually to read a text file, you want an `InputStreamReader` (with an appropriate encoding) wrapping an `InputStream` (e.g. a `FileInputStream`). It's not really ideal to try to do this with `RandomAccessFile` - you *could* read data into a `byte[]` and then convert that into a `String` but there are all kinds of subtleties you'd need to think about.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Is there an alternate method for writing? I've tried using RandomAccessFile.writeChars but it gave me an unwanted NULL character after every char.

Comment: @RandomPerson78642: Well we don't really know enough about your context, or why you're using `RandomAccessFile` to start with. I would personally try to avoid that for text data, in most cases.

Comment: writeChar does not write unwanted null characters, it writes your characters as two byte.

Comment: Okay, nevermind. You were correct, turns out my problems were being caused by mixing up bytes and chars together. I switched everything to bytes and it works perfectly now.